# react native login username not find

Tags: android, react-native

can someone help me, i dont what will i do. this code always error if i setting the username and password. i'am a newbie, this my first work build app with react native

```
export default class Login extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     username: '', 
     password: ''};
  }


  async loginAjax() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('http://panel.erzap.com/web_services/login_json/new.json', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          erzap: {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            }
        })
      });
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      Alert.alert(responseJson.notice);
    } catch(error) {
      Alert.alert(error);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPAUP.jpg)

Comment: This code is working fine...! Your error is from somewhere else... share the entire code.

Comment: I tried `loginAjax` code too, its working fine, If issue is related to username or on password, issue might be related to state and the way you are calling `loginAjax`, may be you need to bind this. Share your code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.loginAjax()}>
     <Text style={styles.btn}>Login</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Replace this part of the code with your code. It's work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code and now it works perfectly.

```js
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.loginAjax.bind(this)}>
<Text style={styles.btn}>Login</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```